# angularjs: using a custom filter with a service

Tags: angularjs

I can find plenty of examples on how to create a custom filter and using it for filtering a set of data.
However, I can't find any example on how to use a filter for filtering using a back-end service. For instance:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" />

<table id="searchTextResults">    
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">
       results go here
  </tr>
</table>
```

Instead of filtering the existing items, typing in the input should make a call to a service for getting results from the server. Does it make sense to use a filter in this case ? Or should I keep the logic in the controller ?

Comment: The above logic is fine if you preload all resource and do filtering on client side but if you want to get result from server on everykeypress then its better to build logic in contoller and back-end

Comment: Ok, you confirm what I thought then. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filter would perform terribly in this situation as filters are executed as part of the each and every $digest loop. In practice it means that a given filter would be executed at least twice per $digest loop so you would have a mass of request to a back-end.

On top of this filters can't be really used reliably to fetch data from the server as filters execute synchronously while back-end calls are async.

In short - stay away from filters that trigger back-end calls.